# Validate SQL committed to Subversion via Jenkins job

Tags: mysql, jenkins, svn, jenkins-plugins

I'm newer to Jenkins and I'm trying to help with an Agile/DevOps transformation. Currently, our system has a SVN repo that developers commit SQL files into, that we later have our DBA run. I have a Jenkins job that reads that repo location and builds upon changes. Is there any way I can have it run that SQL and error out if it hits an error? Or could I define errors that are permissible at ones to throw the red dot at?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute SQLs from ant file using SQL tag (https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sql.html)

However, what you consider is the changes in SVN and changes on DB. In this case, what you need is a to execute each and every change in DDL and DML on the DB to avoid any false-errors.

If you are considering the coding style error, such as avoid "select *", have the SQLs scanned using SonarQube/SonarScanner.